# Querying Mongo UUID from PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have uuid stored in MongoDB:

```
"transactionId" : BinData(3,"/Utm5RS0C5N2/Cwus1rrkw==")
```

But when I try to get this "transactionId" from PHP, I have no luck, there are no results for this query:

```
$query = array("transactionId" => new MongoBinData("/Utm5RS0C5N2/Cwus1rrkw==", MongoBinData::UUID));
$array = $mongo_collection->findOne($query);
var_dump($array);
```

How can I get this "transactionId" from php?

**PS Found solution by myself.** We can find hex value of "transactionId" in Mongo Shell like this:

```
var doc = db['ColletctionName'].findOne({"transactionId" : new BinData (3, "/Utm5RS0C5N2/Cwus1rrkw==")})
doc.transactionId.hex()
fd4b66e514b40b9376fc2c2eb35aeb93
```

As we see the hex value of

```
"transactionId" : BinData(3,"/Utm5RS0C5N2/Cwus1rrkw==")
```

is

```
fd4b66e514b40b9376fc2c2eb35aeb93
```

So we can query to Mongo like this to get "transactionId"  field:

```
$hex = str_replace("-", "", $transaction_id); // remove extra characters
    $msb = substr($hex, 0, 16);
    $lsb = substr($hex, 16, 16);
    $msb = substr($msb, 14, 2).substr($msb, 12, 2).substr($msb, 10, 2).substr($msb, 8, 2).substr($msb, 6, 2).substr($msb, 4, 2).substr($msb, 2, 2).substr($msb, 0, 2);
    $lsb = substr($lsb, 14, 2).substr($lsb, 12, 2).substr($lsb, 10, 2).substr($lsb, 8, 2).substr($lsb, 6, 2).substr($lsb, 4, 2).substr($lsb, 2, 2).substr($lsb, 0, 2);

    $hex = $msb.''.$lsb;
    $hex = pack('H*',$hex); 
$query = array("transactionId" => new MongoBinData ($hex , MongoBinData::UUID));
$array = $mongo_collection->findOne($query);
```

Comment: If you've found the solution yourself, please feel free to [self-answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but don't edit it into the question itself.

Comment: Ok, thanks, James. There were a lot of code, so I decided to put it into original post.